# Multiple y-axis background colors for chart

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

How can I create a background for a chart that looks like this?

[image]

It's got different background colors at certain % levels that correspond to the status. All I see in `ChartArea` is `BackColor`, `BackSecondaryColor`, and `BackGradientStyle` which won't do this. This image was taken from an SSRS report and I am trying to recreate it using C# and the Microsoft charting library. I am pretty sure SSRS uses the same library so it should be possible - I just don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `StripLine`.

```
// Create the stripline for 'gold status'
StripLine sline = new StripLine();
sline.IntervalOffset = 0.6;
sline.StripWidth = 0.25;
sline.Text = "Gold Status";
sline.Interval = 0.0; // this ensures it will not repeat like normal strip lines
sline.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
myChart.AxisY.StripLines.Add(sline);
```

repeat the process for your *silver* and *platinum* strip lines.

Comment: I found I needed to reference the AxisY property of the ChartArea, as follows:  `myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(sline);`