# MPAndroidChart different background colors depending on value?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to have multiple y-axix background colors for a MPAndroidChart chart?

An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688169/multiple-y-axis-background-colors-for-chart).

In its meaning it is similar to LimitLine but the background colors separate the slices.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is **currently not possible**! The background color can only be set at once at this moment.

However it is very likely that this could be included in some future update of this library.